# AWS cognito sign in without password

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am making an application using AWS cognito and Spring Boot. After registering, users confirm their account by email or SMS activation code. After they confirm their account, can I do an automatic session login? Can I start a session without a password only for confirmation cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can perform login for the user without a password using [Custom Authentication Flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-custom-authentication-flow).

You will have to add [Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-challenge.html) to handle your custom auth flow.
In application, you will have to use [AdminInitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html) API call.

Here is some code example to understand the general idea:

```
public void auth(String username) {

    AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(AWS_KEY,
            AWS_SECRET);

    CognitoIdentityProviderClient identityProviderClient =
            CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder()
                    .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                    .region(Region.of(REGION))
                    .build();

    final Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<>();
    authParams.put("USERNAME", username);
    authParams.put("SECRET_HASH", calculateSecretHash(CLIENT_ID,
            CLIENT_SECRET, username));

    final AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = AdminInitiateAuthRequest.builder()
            .authFlow(AuthFlowType.CUSTOM_AUTH)
            .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .userPoolId(POOL_ID)
            .authParameters(authParams)
            .build();

    AdminInitiateAuthResponse result = identityProviderClient.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);

    System.out.println(result.authenticationResult().accessToken());
    System.out.println(result.authenticationResult().idToken());
}

private String calculateSecretHash(String userPoolClientId, String userPoolClientSecret, String userName) {
    final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";

    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(
            userPoolClientSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
            HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        mac.update(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(userPoolClientId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawHmac);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while calculating ");
    }
}
```

You will also need to add dependecies for AWS SDK:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.57</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>cognitoidentityprovider</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.57</version>
</dependency>
```

And add Lambda for "Define Auth Challange" trigger of you user pool:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // Don't do any checks just say that authentication is successfull
  event.response.issueTokens = true;
  event.response.failAuthentication = false;
  return event;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Yuriy P is perfect.
Additionally, in the case Cognito's client application does not set for password, you can ignore "SECRET_HASH"
The code is simplifier as below:

```
public AdminInitiateAuthResult adminInitiateAuth(String account, String clientId) {
    final Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<>();
    authParams.put("USERNAME", account);

    final AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest();
    authRequest.setAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.CUSTOM_AUTH);
    authRequest.setClientId(clientId);
    authRequest.setUserPoolId(poolId);
    authRequest.setAuthParameters(authParams);

    AdminInitiateAuthResult result = cognitoIdentityClient.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);

    System.out.println("accessToken:" + result.getAuthenticationResult().getAccessToken());
    System.out.println("idToken:" +result.getAuthenticationResult().getIdToken());
    return result;
}
```